# Sqoop from Presto Database, [Teradata][JDBC](11975) Unsupported transaction isolation level: 2

Tags: sqoop, presto

I am able to connect and query Presto database using Cli, Spark etc

But when I try to Sqoop import from a PrestoDB instance into S3, I am getting this transaction isolation error:

```
    8/02/26 03:03:46 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
18/02/26 03:03:46 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
18/02/26 03:03:46 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
18/02/26 03:03:46 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
18/02/26 03:03:46 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
18/02/26 03:03:46 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM alarm_types AS t WHERE 1=0
18/02/26 03:03:46 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
18/02/26 03:05:56 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata][JDBC](11975) Unsupported transaction isolation level: 2.
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata][JDBC](11975) Unsupported transaction isolation level: 2.
    at com.teradata.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.common.SConnection.setTransactionIsolation(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:891)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
18/02/26 03:05:56 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

I tried with Standard Facebook Driver jar and also with Teradata Presto Jdbc jar, getting the same error with both these drivers.

Exception when Facebook driver is used:

```
    18/02/26 19:22:20 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Transactions are not yet supported
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Transactions are not yet supported
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoConnection.setTransactionIsolation(PrestoConnection.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:891)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
18/02/26 19:22:20 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Here is my Sqoop command:

```
sqoop import \
    -libjars $teradata_jar_path --driver $teradata_driver \
    --verbose \
    --connect jdbc:presto://xxx/<db> \
    --table <tablename> --target-dir s3://<s3-path> \
     --relaxed-isolation
```

Please note that i tried with "--relaxed-isolation" as-well, but getting same error. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post stacktrace when Facebook Driver is used?

Comment: Thanks @kokosing, i updated my question with stacktrace when facebook driveer is used. Any clues?

Comment: What version of Presto you are using. See that in 0.195 transactions are supported: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-jdbc/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/jdbc/PrestoConnection.java#L243

Comment: I am currently using Presto Version: 0.179-T.1 and presto-jdbc-0.184.jar driver.  Thanks for your hint on version 0.195, will check it out.

Comment: After switching to 0.195, i am able to overcome Transaction issue, but now getting com.facebook.presto.jdbc.NotImplementedException: Method Connection.prepareStatement is not yet implemented

Comment: Prepared statements are not yet available in Facebook Presto. It is work in progress. It requires a new client-server communication protocol which is on the way. If want you may want to visit this page https://www.starburstdata.com/download/ where you will be able to get 0.189-t or 0.188-e version with prepared statements supported.

Comment: I copied the above comment which appeared to be an answer so you could accept and vote it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade your Presto installation. I suggest you to use the most recent one.

Notice that support for transactions using SQL statements or the standard JDBC mechanism was added in 0.189: https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-0.189.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Kokosing, our production Presto version is currently 0.179, I am proposing an upgrade.

Comment: Hi @kokosing, I tried with Facebook Presto driver version: presto-jdbc-0.205.jar    but still getting error:  18/07/12 10:47:02 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM hive.thor_fttx.v_ams_inv_ont_optical_measurements AS t WHERE 1=0
18/07/12 10:47:02 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: Query failed (#20180712_104701_01127_ptpsh): Connector supported isolation level READ UNCOMMITTED does not meet requested isolation level READ COMMITTED